# Why does my code compile in VB.NET but the equivalent in C# fails

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-2.0, vb.net-to-c#

The following VB.NET code works:

```
Dim request As Model.LearnerLogbookReportRequest = New Model.LearnerLogbookReportRequest
request.LearnerIdentityID = Convert.ToInt32(Session("identityID"))
request.EntryVersion = LearnerLogbookEntryVersion.Full

Dim reportRequestService As IReportRequestService = ServiceFactory.GetReportRequestService(ServiceInvoker.LearnerLogbook)
        reportRequestservice.SaveRequest(request)
```

The following C# code fails to compile:

```
LearnerLogbookReportRequest request = new LearnerLogbookReportRequest();
request.LearnerIdentityID = theLearner.ID;
request.EntryVersion = LearnerLogbookEntryVersion.Full;

IReportRequestService reportRequestService = ServiceFactory.GetReportRequestService(ServiceInvoker.LearnerLogbook);

reportRequestService.SaveRequest(ref request);
```

The LearnerLogbookReportRequest is declared as:

```
Public Class LearnerLogbookReportRequest
    Inherits AbstractReportRequest
```

Error:

```
Error   11  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref RACQ.ReportService.Common.Model.LearnerLogbookReportRequest' to 'ref RACQ.ReportService.Common.Model.AbstractReportRequest'    C:\p4projects\WEB_DEVELOPMENT\SECURE_ASPX\main-dev-codelines\LogbookSolution-DR6535\RACQ.Logbook.Web\Restful\SendLogbook.cs 64  50  RACQ.Logbook.Web
```

Why is the C# version failing to compile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VB is rather looser with `ByRef` parameters than C# is. For example, it allows you to pass properties by reference. C# doesn't allow this.

In a similar way, with [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) off, VB allows you to use an argument which is a subtype of the declared parameter. As a short but complete program, consider this:

```
Imports System

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim p As String = "Original"
        Foo(p)
        Console.WriteLine(p)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Foo(ByRef p As Object)
        p = "Changed"
    End Sub
End Class
```

That works in VB, but the equivalent in C# wouldn't... and for good reason. It's dangerous. In this case, we're using a string variable and we happen to change `p` to refer to another string, but if we change the body of `Foo` to:

```
p = new Object()
```

Then we get an exception at execution time:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'Object' to type 'String' is not valid.

Basically `ref` is compile-time type-safe in C#, but `ByRef` isn't type-safe in VB with Option Strict off.

If you add:

```
Option Strict On
```

to the program in VB, however (or just change the defaults for your project) you should see the same problem in VB:

```
error BC32029: Option Strict On disallows narrowing from type 'Object' to type
'String' in copying the value of 'ByRef' parameter 'p' back to the matching
argument.

        Foo(p)
            ~
```

This suggests that you're currently coding without Option Strict... I'd recommend using it ASAP.

Comment: +1 - I suggested on Meta that new posters to the VB.NET tag are suggested to check their Option Strict Setting http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144007/inform-new-posters-tagging-vb-net-to-check-option-strict-setting but it was voted down. I added a note to the Tag Wiki however for what its worth. This setting really should be on by default.